# Error [TS2344] when I type a generic for any class

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an error that seems a bit strange to me

I have the following:

```
class A {
    some?: string

    constructor(some: string) {
        this.some = some
    }
}

type LikeClass<TClass extends { new (...args: any[]): TClass }> = Pick<TClass, (keyof TClass)>

// Error here.
const attrs: LikeClass<A> = {
    some: 'hello'
}
```

But I received the following error:

[image]

The `{ new (...args: any[]): TClass }` generic is supposed to be used to type any class or constructor, or not?

even in the typescript documentation this type is used, but it doesn't happen as expected for me

I'm very confused

For example: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators)